# How to get notified each time the value increased

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have two threads.One is for incrementing the value.For each increment i neet to be notified the main thread.
Below is my main Thread which is a activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int progressStatus = 1;
    private TextView textView;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        ProgressUpdate b = new ProgressUpdate();
        b.start();
        Log.e("SAMEERA", "Satrting ProgressUpdate");
        synchronized (b) {
            try {

                Log.e("SAMEERA", "synchronized synchronized");
                Log.e("SAMEERA", "progressStatus is "+b.total);
                b.wait();


                Log.e("SAMEERA", "progressStatus is "+b.total);
                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                textView.setText(progressStatus + "/" + progressBar.getMax());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
        }


    }
}
```

Below is my increment thread.

```
package com.example.zwtouch;

import android.util.Log;

public class ProgressUpdate extends Thread {

    int total;

    public void run() {
        total=0;
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                total += i;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.e("SAMEERA", "run run total is "+i);
                notify();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I need to notified each time if total is increased.But its not happening.After the for loop is finished it calls the main thread..where is the error ?

Answer (score 3):

## Option 1

Use [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

1. Populate `ProgressUpdate` with `ProgressBar` and `Handler` objects.
2. On each progress use the `Handler` to update the `ProgressBar`

like this:

```
public class ProgressUpdate extends Thread {

    int total;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    Handler mHandler;

    public ProgressUpdate(Handler h, ProgressBar pb) {
        mHandler = h;
        mProgressBar = pb;
    }

    public void run() {
        total=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
           // Update the progress bar via a Handler
           mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   mProgressBar.setProgress(i);
               }
           });
        }
    }
}
```

**setup like this**

```
new ProgressUpdate(handler, progressBar).start();
```

## Option 2 (recommended)

This is another approach, You could use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to achieve this aim. The advantage of this way is that both `onProgressUpdate` and `onPostExecute` runs on UI-Thread.

**Make this class internal of MainActivity**

```
private class ProgressUpdate extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

     protected Integer doInBackground(Void... dummy) {
          int total = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                total += i;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.e("SAMEERA", "run run total is "+i);
                // Notify UI Thread
                publishProgress(i);
            }
         return total;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... i) {
         // do something with 'i' on UI Thread   
         progressBar.setProgress(i);      
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Integer total) {
         // do something with 'total' on UI Thread
         // for instance
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
  }
```

**Setup ProgressUpdate on onCreate like this**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ... 
    new ProgressUpdate().execute();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Actually i don't think this is working for my case.I need to show progressbar for downloading several files.So when each download complete it trigger the callback method.So i can update the file count and i need to show the progressbar.

Comment: Then handler way may help. Each time a download has completed, do a mHandler.post to update main activity.